# VBA: Call a Macro with a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner in VBA and i have done a script which would call different macros according to the sheet name which is assigned to a variable `SheetName`. I'm trying to execute the below code and I'm getting a Compile Error. Hope you guys can help me!!

```
Sub ScrubeCareOutput()

Dim SheetName, Header, PolicyNumber As String
Dim CheckPoint As Integer

StartTime = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("ConsolidatedData").Select
Range("P:P").Cut
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
Range("A1").Select

'Deleting old sheet
Application.StatusBar = "Calculating Loop .."
Sheets("Reference").Select
Range("L2").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
SheetName = ActiveCell.Value

'Scrubbing Output
Do Until SheetName = ""

Application.StatusBar = "Scrubbing " & SheetName & " Output.."
Sheets(SheetName).Select
Range("a1").Select

If IsEmpty(Range("A2")) = False Then
Range("A2").Select
Header = ActiveCell.Value
End If

'Deleting Headers

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Header
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="©Copyright Nebo Systems, Inc."
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Powered by ECARE?"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Range("1:1").Delete

'Scrubbing Data
Call SheetName

'Creating fields
For i = 1 To 4
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
Next

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Account Number"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Mnemonic"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Begin Date"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "End Date"

'Formulating data
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -3).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(E2,ConsolidatedData!$A:$S,3,0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(E2,ConsolidatedData!$A:$S,16,0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(E2,ConsolidatedData!$A:$S,17,0)"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=VLOOKUP(E2,ConsolidatedData!$A:$S,18,0)"

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 3)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("a1").Select

'Formatting data
Application.StatusBar = "Formatting " & SheetName & " Output.."
With ActiveSheet
.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
.Cells.Font.Size = "10"
End With
Range("1:1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Range("A1").Select

'Save data
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Sheets("Reference").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
SheetName = ActiveCell.Value
Else

Sheets("Reference").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
SheetName = ActiveCell.Value

End If
Loop

Sheets("UB92Monitor").Select

'Confirmation message
ActiveWorkbook.Save

EndTime = Format((Now() - StartTime), "HH:MM:SS")
Application.StatusBar = False
MsgBox "Data scrubbed successfully in " & EndTime, vbOKOnly, "Data Scrubbing Status"

End Sub
```

Comment: `SheetName` is a variable.  Do you have another `Sub` or `Function` called `SheetName`?

Comment: Which line is the compile error on? what error message are you getting?

Comment: Can you reproduce the error with minimal code? Please read [mcve]

Comment: You also have a stray `Else` and `End If` at the bottom of the loop that aren't part of an `If` statement.

Comment: @Comintern SheetName is a Variable. And i would get the Sheet name in the variable were it should execute a sub (Macro) which i've created with the Sheet Name.

Comment: I'm Sorry @Mat'sMug! I'm new to VBA and still i would learn much before posting my question..

Comment: Your first line (where you declare multiple variables separated with a comma) is declaring all but PolicyNumber as a variant. I am guessing that there is a chance you are accidentally assigning the sheet (object) to sheetname instead of the Sheet.Name property.

Comment: Nevermind. I see where you are using the cell value to assign sheetname. Instead of using "Call SheetName" try "Application.Run SheetName".

Comment: Awesome @BrandonBarney! Works like a charm. Thanks All!!

Comment: Last comment, I promise. Read up on avoiding "select" and "activate". It is very common for those new to VBA to do this, but it should be avoided unless absolutely neccesary. For example, where you have "ActiveCell.Offset.Select" and then "ActiveCell.Value = " you could do "Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Value = Somevalue" and tackle everything all at once (much cleaner and faster).